# Segregating content in a blog for 2 different readers

Tags: content-restriction, split

I'd like to have a blog that covers two topics, mathematics and interactive fiction.  However, because the mathematics is more serious, for my job, I'd like to hide the interactive fiction when the user is on the home page AND when the user is reading a math post, but have it visible when the user is reading another interactive fiction post.

Is this possible? Essentially I want to do what MathOverflow does with stackexchange, where MO posts appear in stackexchange sidebars but other sites don't appear in MO's sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking about widgets - then you can use plugins like [widget logic](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/) where you can easily create rules for displaying widgets. Let say your posts are separated into 2 categories - interactive functions and mathematics. Then you can create two different widgets displaying the latest post for the two different categories and set their logic to be like - all latest posts from category "Mathematics" to appear only on single posts from category "Mathematics" and "Home Page" ( and the same for category "Interactive Function"). 
Hope this will help you a bit.